# How to insert multiple rows into embedded view from a subform? Lotus Notes

Tags: view, lotus-notes, rows

I have a section that contains a subform ( containing 3 editable fields for the user ).

Then I have an embedded view categorized having two actions: Add and Trash.

What i want to do: After the user complete the 3 fields and then press Add, the first row in the embedded view will appear. ( This easy thing I did ). But then after the first click on Add, I want that all the 3 fields to be refreshed, all of them to have as their value: "".

After, if the user wants to add another row into the embedded view (with different values), in my case it is overwrited on the 1st row. I want to be separate rows in order.

I tried something with `@Command(ViewRefreshFields)` into the Add action code but I didn't make it to work. Please help, J. U.

Answer (score 1):

Jazir, I'm guessing that you also go by the names "Florin G Mihalache", "Josh Mitchell" and "Yveniss Ltoreau", and I've been following the development of your application along with many other professional Notes developers.

I really think you need to go back to the very first basics, and work out the difference between forms, subforms, documents, views, embedded views, and other important components of Lotus Notes databases.

I strongly suspect that for a couple of weeks you have been trying to use a form to create other documents, via a subform, to be displayed in an embedded view in that form, when what you should be using is just a view, and documents.  Perhaps you might need to use pages, outlines and framesets.  It is very important that you understand these basic concepts before confusing the people who have tried to help you, to whom you may have lied.

I have voted your question down, not just because you have shown a lack of research, but because you appear to keep switching ID when people lose patience with you.  I will undo that vote if I become convinced that you are not Florin.

Comment: Although I've answered, I agree with Phil.  This question sounds like someone attempting to use advanced Notes development concepts to solve a problem the wrong way due to lack of knowledge of basic Notes development concepts.

Comment: In fact, having had this going through the back of my mind for far too long, I think what Florin (etc) is trying to do is something along the lines of an embedded editor.  I suspect he's using the form to add documents to a view, confusing Notes and relational databases, making the assumption that view=table, doc=row, form=input dialog.  If he could get past that confusion, and work out how Notes works, he'll probably scrap his database and start again from scratch.  I can't believe I'm still offering him ideas though!

Answer (score 0):

The documents displayed in an embedded view are controlled by the view's selection formula. You haven't shown that.  You haven't shown your code in the Add button.  You haven't shown what properties you have set on the embedded view -- e.g., show single category.  So you're not giving us quite enough info to diagnose your problem and help you.

But in general, I think that if you want to control the order of insertion of individual documents into an embedded list, perhaps using an embedded folder would be a better idea than an embedded view.

Comment: 1. SELECT (Form = "fm_main") 'the view's selection formula. fm_main is the form that contains the subform . 2. Add action: @Command([FileSave]); @Command([ViewRefreshFields]) 'here I think is the problem, because the 3 fields are not set to "", after the click on Add. 3. The embedded view has @Text(@DocumentUniqueId) as the show single category.

Comment: You are showing a single category, and the category is selected by @DocumentUniqueID of the current document.  So it is only possible for the embedded view to show one document.  It seems like you are just replacing the values of the fields in the current document and redisplaying those fields in the one document that shows in the view.  You probably need to be adding the input fields to multi-valued fields, and displaying the multi-valued fields as columns in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So, I need to check the property of the fields: Allow multiple values? Also, after click the Add action, the value of the fields don't modifies.

Comment: Yes, allow multiple values.  In order to append another value, you need to use the syntax saveField := savedField : inputField.  This is very, very, very basic Notes development.